# Style Facebook comments iframe

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, styles, comments

I have added the HTML5 version of the new facebook comments plugin. I am currently using the dark theme as it is the only color scheme that "fits" with my website. However, the dark theme has this ugly box around the new comment box (not the previous comments). I've inspected the source and can play around with the values in googles inspect source. But when I save it to CSS it doesn't work. I'm a novice to customizing iFrames and would love it if anyone could help me out.

In summary, I want to change the grey background that comes with the "Dark" theme and the black background of the actual comment text input.

http://i57.tinypic.com/2937dzq.png  <--- here is a visual reference

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible due iframe cross domain policy

Comment: are there any other plugins that give this functionality to your knowledge?

Comment: AFAIK, no, but you can style the comments, if you use the API to get them

Comment: can you at least change the text color? I'd rather use the light theme but it causes text to be black. Which on my background is unreadable.

Comment: No, you can't do even a minor change in cross domain iframes